# Select field descriptive or numeric keys

Tags: entities

I have created a field of type `List (text)` with widget `Select list`.
After editing most of its settings, it came to complete its `Allowed values list`.
Following the help's text instructions, the values should have this form `key|label` and here is my question:

Should I use descriptive or numeric keys for the values (and why)?

> The `key` is the stored value

Does this (keys) selection will have any impact in the future if for example I want to use these values for aggregation (with views or not)?

Answer (score 1):

The `key|label` format is for scenarios where you want to present a different, user-friendly, label that differs from the underlying, machine-readable, storage. For example, a country select list that you want represent in the [2-character ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes) format while showing the official country names to present to the user selecting it.

In the above scenario, regardless of using the `key|label` format or not, the underlying data will be represented as a string (`VARCHAR`) since it's a *Field (text)* field type. If your underlying data needs to be represented as numeric, then you should use the *List (Integer)* (or other number types) field type as it will be stored as `INT` within the DB column.

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked but thanks for answering, one up!